# Vim settings for Erlang

Tags: vim, erlang

Does anyone want to share their erlang vim settings? It seems I can't make it work at all and the worst part is that it doesn't auto-indent automatically.

Is there something outhere called vim-erlang, as in vim-python or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first two hits on google for erlang and vim yields [Erlang plugin package](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1584) and [vim-erlang](http://github.com/pangloss/vim-erlang). Did you try those out already?

Answer (score 20):

The most recent version of [vimerl](http://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl) can be found there. New features were added and many bugs were also fixed:

- Syntax highlight
- Code folding
- Code completion (based on `Module:module_info/1` to use the Erlang introspection mechanism)
- Auto-indent
- QuickFix
- Wrangler support (the refactoring Erlang tool)

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](http://github.com/pangloss/vim-erlang/raw/a5b881eb1ed5ab32a0a51a473170d41b86698ecd/syntax/erlang.vim). It's part of a [bigger package](http://github.com/pangloss/vim-erlang) that would probably be useful, too.