# Settings do not work, no code folding, no code completion

Tags: erlang, vim

I found some recommendations about Vim + Erlang:

> [Vim settings for Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774315/vim-settings-for-erlang)

and tried to configure it.

I have the following problems:

- Code folding  - does not work
- Code completion -  does not work

Here is my `.vimrc` file:

```
set nu!
syn on
set foldenable
nmap <F9> :SCCompile
nmap <F10> :SCCompileRun
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enable vimerl:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

folding by space button:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Space> @=(foldlevel('.')?'za':'l')<CR>
vnoremap <Space> zf
```

Code completion:

```
let g:erlangManPath='/opt/local/lib/erlang/man'
```

for local completion press CTRL+P

for omni completion write the name of a module (e.g. `my_mod:') press CTRL-X CTRL-O to activate

Answer (score 1):

**Vimerl** have improved, try its latest release (http://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl):

### Features

- Syntax highlighting
- Code indenting
- Code folding
- Code omni completion
- Syntax checking with quickfix support
- Code skeletons for the OTP behaviours
- Uses configuration from Rebar
- Pathogen compatible (http://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)